# The query gives single row query returns more than one row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show staff_code, staff_name and dept_name for those who have taken one book.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT SM.STAFF_CODE,SM.STAFF_NAME,DM.DEPT_NAME,BT.BOOK_CODE
FROM STAFF_MASTER SM,DEPARTMENT_MASTER DM,BOOK_TRANSACTIONS BT 
WHERE SM.DEPT_CODE =DM.DEPT_CODE
AND SM.STAFF_CODE = (
  SELECT STAFF_CODE
  FROM BOOK_TRANSACTIONS
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  GROUP BY STAFF_CODE)
```

It gives the error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row.

How to solve this?

Comment: put the nested query into a `HAVING` clause

Answer (score 1):

Change `=` to `IN`:

```
WHERE SM.STAFF_CODE IN (SELECT ...)
```

Because the select returns multiple values, using equals won't work, but `IN` returns true if any of the values in a list match. The list can be a hard-coded CSV list, or a select with one column like your query is.

That will fix the error, but you also need to remove `BOOK_TRANSACTIONS` from the table list and remove `BOOK_CODE` from the select list.

After making these changes, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT SM.STAFF_CODE,SM.STAFF_NAME,DM.DEPT_NAME
FROM STAFF_MASTER SM,DEPARTMENT_MASTER DM
WHERE SM.DEPT_CODE =DM.DEPT_CODE
AND SM.STAFF_CODE IN (
  SELECT STAFF_CODE
  FROM BOOK_TRANSACTIONS
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  GROUP BY STAFF_CODE)
```

I recommend learning the modern (now over 25 year old) JOIN syntax.